# NSString substring wont compare

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

My string comparison keeps returning false and I dont understand why.  Even my nslog says the value is correct.  Do you know why my comparison keeps returning false even though the strings appear to be the same?  If I step through the program type shows SV as its value. I have ensured there are no spaces in this string as well. We get the first two chars of this:
SV2B799E5B-4306-4965-B5DD-944D3970E6B6

```
NSString *fPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[directoryContent objectAtIndex:x]];
    NSString *fName = [directoryContent objectAtIndex:x];
    NSString *type =  [fName substringToIndex:2];

    NSLog(@"TYPE: %@",type);

    if ([type caseInsensitiveCompare:@"SV"])
    {
        NSData *file = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fPath];

        if (file)
        {
            [[WebService sharedWebService]saveVolunteer:nil :YES :[directoryContent  objectAtIndex:x] :file];
            [file release];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[NSString -caseInsensitiveCompare:]` does not return a `BOOL`, it returns an `NSComparisonResult`.  This is going to be 0 if the strings are equal (in a case insensitive fashion), which is why you're seeing that result.

Invert your result and you'll be set, or to be more correct, check to see if it is == `NSOrderedSame`.

Answer (score 2):

The method you are calling returns an NSComparisonResult, not a boolean value. It so happens that an NSComparisonResult of equal has the value zero, which is interpreted as false.

Answer (score 0):

caseInsensitiveCompare: returns a NSComparisonResult. Try [type caseInsensitiveCompare:@"SV"] == NSOrderedSame